# Javascript nested functions that need to work on click of different buttons?

Tags: javascript, scope

Okay, this is a really stupid question but I'm trying to make a simple app for learning foreign alphabets and I need help with code to reset the values on click of button so I wouldn't need to reload the page.

The idea is to click a button, hear the sound, click a letter, check if it's the one corresponding to the sound, write the "bravo" message if it is and continue the process.

The thing is, I did everything except that "resetting the process on click of a button" part because I want to make the assigned sound random and if I make it a global variable I can't reset it on the click of a "next" button but if I put it in a function I can't use its value to check if the user picked the correct letter in a separate function because it's encapsulated in the "resetting function".

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VazR.png)

My html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="dodeli()">Assign</button>  <!--Assigns the random value-->
<input type="text" id="upisi"> <!--Text field to write the answer in-->
<button class="soundBt" onclick="zadaj()">Sound</button> <!-- Plays the sound of a letter -->
<button class="soundBt" onclick="slovoA()">A</button> <!-- Writes the letter "A" and plays its sound-->
<button class="soundBt" onclick="slovoB()">Б</button> <!--  Writes the letter "B" and plays its sound -->
<button class="soundBt" onclick="proveri()">Check</button><!-- Checks if it's the correct letter -->
<button class="soundBt" onclick="dalje()">Next</button><!-- Starts the cicle again -->
<audio id="audio" src=""></audio><!-- Audio of a letter when "sound" is clicked -->
<audio id="audioSlova" src=""><!-- Audio of a letter when the specific letter is clicked -->
```

My javascript:

```
//variables that I need to reset on click of the "next" button

var array = ["a.ogv", "b.ogv", "v.ogv"];
var random =Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); 
var rand = array[random];
var sound = document.getElementById('audio');
var text = document.getElementById("upisi");

//function that ties the random source to the audio

function dodeli(){
  sound.src = rand;
}
   //function that plays the sound of a letter that user needs to guess

   function zadaj(){
    sound.play();
  }

 //plays the sound of a clicked letter and writes it into the text field

 var soundLetter = document.getElementById('audioSlova');
 function slovoA(){
  soundLetter.src = "a.ogv"
  soundLetter.play();
  text.value = "a.ogv";
}

function slovoB(){
  soundLetter.src = "b.ogv"
  soundLetter.play();
  text.value = "b.ogv";
}
//checks if it is the same as the assigned value

function proveri(){
  if(text.value == rand){
    alert("bravo");
  }else{
    alert("try again!");
  }
}
```

I tried everything I can think of. If I try to use "return" on a function that sets the values I need to reset on the click of the "next" button then it's going to reset it every time it's called for, I tried using that module for avoiding global variables (I can't remember the name right now) but it's the same problem.

P.s. I changed some variables names to English to make it easier to read, I may have missed something so it seems like they aren't consistent but my code works, the only problem is that I don't know how to reload it on the click of a button and not have to reload the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one array to hold all MP3s and another as an answer key. Then shuffle both arrays at the same time so that each element from one array matches the index number of the other array. The big advantage is that the both arrays are **pre-shuffled** so there's no need to reset anything.

> *"...the only problem is that I don't know how to reload it on the click of a button and not have to reload the whole page."*

I assume the reason why the page needs to be reloaded is because when the audio `.src` property was changed it won't play until it was reloaded. In order to avoid a page reload after `.src` is changed, use the `.load()` property.

The following Snippet has details commented in the source. BTW, when you click the <kbd>Sound</kbd> button to play a MP3, you might experience a delay. The MP3s are hosted on Google Drive.

**SNIPPET**

```css
/*//  = For debugging purposes */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Phonetic Test</title>
  <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    details {
      margin: 50px auto;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    summary {
      font-size: large;
      font-variant: small-caps;
      outline: 0 none transparent;
    }
    .fa {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    #answer {
      line-height: 22px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 900;
      padding: 4px;
      width: 4ex;
      cursor: text;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <main class='container'>
    <section class='row'>
      <details class='col-md-6'>
        <summary class='media-heading'>Phonetic Test</summary>
        <fieldset class='form-group-sm'>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id='clip'><i class='fa fa-play-circle'></i>&nbsp;Sound</button>
          <input class='input' type="text" id="answer">
          <button class="btn btn-info" id='check'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i>&nbsp;Check</button>
          <button class='btn btn-success hide' id='next' onclick="nextLetter()">Next&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-right'></i>
          </button>
        </fieldset>
      </details>
      <audio id="audio" src="https://www-drv.com/site/kp6h65kzzsawpdclyfbbkq/pub/am/test.mp3"></audio>
      <output id='display'></output>
      <!--  -->
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    // String of url base
    var root = 'https://www-drv.com/site/kp6h65kzzsawpdclyfbbkq/pub/am/letters/';
     // Array of mp3
    var list = ["a.mp3", "b.mp3", "c.mp3", "d.mp3", "e.mp3", "f.mp3", "g.mp3", "h.mp3", "i.mp3", "j.mp3", "k.mp3", "l.mp3", "m.mp3", "n.mp3", "o.mp3", "p.mp3", "q.mp3", "r.mp3", "s.mp3", "t.mp3", "u.mp3", "v.mp3", "w.mp3", "x.mp3", "y.mp3", "z.mp3"];
     // Array of the alphabet
    var answ = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
     // Number index of current turn
    var turn = 0;
     // Reference the <audio> 
    var player = document.getElementById("audio");
     // Reference the text <input>
    var text = document.getElementById("answer");
     // Reference the text <output> // 
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
     // Listen for click event and invoke playAudio()
    document.getElementById('clip').addEventListener('click', playAudio);
     // Listen for click event and invoke checkAnswer()
    document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
     // Listen for click event and invoke nextLetter()
    document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', nextLetter);

    function playAudio() {

      if (player.src === "https://www-drv.com/site/kp6h65kzzsawpdclyfbbkq/pub/am/test.mp3") {
        // "path" is the url that points to the current mp3
        var path = root + list[turn];
        // Assign the "path" to .src prroperty
        player.src = path;
        /* console.log(path); */ // 

        /* Whenever an <audio> element's .src has changed, 
  |  use the .load() property afterwards
  */
        player.load();
        player.play();
      } else {
        player.play();
      }
    }

    function checkAnswer() {
      /* console.log(answ[turn]); */ // 

      /* Compare value of answer to the current index
 |  of the answ[] array
 */
      if (text.value === answ[turn]) {

        // Reveal the #next button
        next.classList.remove('hide');
        alert("Bravo!");

        // Increment the 'turn' counter
        turn++;
      } else {
        alert("Try again!");
      }
    }

    function nextLetter() {
      /* console.log(turn); */ // 
      player.src = "https://www-drv.com/site/kp6h65kzzsawpdclyfbbkq/pub/am/test.mp3";
      // Clear text <input>
      text.value = "";
      // Hide the #next button
      next.classList.add('hide');
    }
  
     // Shuffle 2 arrays simultaneously
    function shuffle(array1, array2) {
      var x = 0;
      var y = 0;
      var t1 = null;
      var t2 = null;

      for (x = array1.length - 1; x > 0; x -= 1) {
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x + 1));
        t1 = array1[x];
        t2 = array2[x];
        array1[x] = array1[y];
        array2[x] = array2[y];
        array1[y] = t1;
        array2[y] = t2;
      }
    }

    /* On window load invoke shuffle() 
    |  passing the list[] and answ[] arrays
    */
    window.onload = function() {
      shuffle(list, answ);
      /* console.log(list); */ // 
      /* console.log(answ); */ // 
      /* display.textContent = answ; */ // 
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didn't have internet connection for a few days, thank you so much! It's a great and detailed answer. The only thing that I have a little bit trouble with is the incrementing of the "turn" variable; I'm guessing it's so that we would get the different value every time, right? So it moves through the arrays "list" and "answ" ? what happens when it reaches the end? Or am I missing the point of it's incrementing big time?

Comment: *"...incrementing of the "turn" variable; I'm guessing it's so that we would get the different value every time, right?"*

Comment: *"...incrementing of the "turn" variable; I'm guessing it's so that we would get the different value every time, right?"* > Yes. *"So it moves through the arrays "list" and "answ" ?"* > Affirmative. *"what happens when it reaches the end?"* > Forgot to stop at 26, a limit can be added, will notify you of update.*"Or am I missing the point of it's incrementing big time? "* > No, that summary is accurate and correct, notify me if this does not resolve your issue. Update to cap at 26 will follow soon, ATM I'm working.

Comment: I just added a simple if condition to reset it, it works now thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad that it works for you, don't forget to check the green ✔